# Partition dataframe to overlapping segments

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, datetimeindex

I have a dataframe with time indices and need to partition it into overlapping segments (say 5 days in length with 1 day offset).

Here is a sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd    
i=pd.date_range('05-01-2015', '21-05-2018', freq='D')
x=pd.DataFrame(index=i, data = np.random.randint(0, 100, len(i)))
```

After partitioning the indices of the segments should range respectively from `2015-05-01` to `2015-05-05`, from `2015-05-02` to `2015-05-06`, from `2015-05-03` to `2015-05-08` etc. I assume there should be some trick with `groupby` to do it, but couldn't come up with an efficient implementation.

As a reference, this is implemented in [mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html):

`Partition[list,n,d]` - generates sublists with offset d.

I would greatly appreciate any insight you guys can provide.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the date format you're using, is it `DD-MM-YYYY` or `MM-DD-YYYY`?

Comment: I think you want `df.rolling(5)`? As in a rolling window of 5 rows: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html. This also has "offset" capability, for a fixed time period, if your time series is not uniform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @alkasm pointed out, you can perform aggregate calculations on 5-day partitions using your sample dataframe using `rolling` in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd    
i = pd.date_range('05-01-2015', '21-05-2018', freq='D')
x = pd.DataFrame(index=i, data = np.random.randint(0, 100, len(i)))

x.rolling(5).sum()
```

The trick with this is, it calculates the aggregate function looking *backwards*, so you may need to expand your index to include the four days prior. A row in your dataframe with index `2018-05-06` with a 5-row `rolling()` call would represent the segment `2018-05-02` to `2018-05-06` inclusive (which is 5 days).